# How to compare the instance of UITextField

Tags: iphone

I have 3 UITextFileds on a view, and I want to apply logic in UITextFieldDelegate method only in two of them, how do I determine the UITextField that triggered the call backs?

Many thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, simple pointer comparison works, since you just want to check for object identity.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
   if (textField != theIgnoredTextField) {
      ...
```

Alternatively, you could assign `.tag`s to the text field.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
   if (textField.tag != 37) {
      ...
```

The advantage is you don't need to store the reference to `theIgnoredTextField`, and the tag can be set from Interface Builder, but it relies on a recognizing magic number "37".

Comment: ...or the compiled enumerated constant `KTMIgnoredTextFieldTag`. I use that a lot in table view cell configuration.

Comment: @Graham: That's good if the view is constructed entirely from code, but AFAIK in IB you can't enter a non-integer like "KTMIgnoredTextFieldTag".

Comment: No, but you do reduce the profusion of magic numbers from everywhere you might need to use the textfield to 2.

Comment: You can always assign the tag to a IB made element when its ViewController's viewDid/WillLoad method. That said, you should ditch IB but for the most basic things. Creating everything in code is faster and provides a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 4):

The delegate methods have a textfield parameter which is a point to the textfield object.  You can compare that parameter to your textfield objects to see which one it is.

```
UITextField *field1, *field2, *field3;
```

In your delegate method you can compare the parameter:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == field1) {
        // do something special for field 1
    } ...
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the delegate methods, such as `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` all you need to do is do something like

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if (textField == myFirstTextField)
{
//blah
}
else if (textField == mySecondTextField)
{
//etc etc.
}
else
{
//WHEE!
}
}//method end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the pointers if you keep references to them in your class ivars or you can use UIView's tag property, whichever you like more.